# Create linkied server encrypted from sqlserver 2019 to 2008r2 using Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oledb, linked-server

I have som sql server 2008 r2 that I want to connect to
it have force encryption set to NO and some expired certyficate

Now, from new sql server 2019 I want to make new linked server connection

So, I have

```
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'PB01_ENC2', @srvproduct=N'mssqlserver', @provider=N'MSOLEDBSQL19', @datasrc=N'PB01', @provstr=N'TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=false;'
```

and this add linkedserver fine hoever when i want connect i get
[image]

why is that? i known that cert expired but `TrustServerCertificate=True` should handle this ? or in  Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server it need to be specified somehow diferent?

`Encrypt=true;` does not change anyhing here...

please advise
best regards

Comment: “ Second, the default value has changed from no/false to Mandatory. This change means that connections are encrypted by default. Previously, the driver would encrypt connections if explicitly set by the user and/or mandated by the SQL Server when the server side property Force Encryption was set to yes. To use old default behavior, include Encrypt=Optional; in the provider connection string, or Use Encryption for Data=Optional; in the IDataInitialize connection string”https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/major-version-differences?view=sql-server-ver16#encryption-property-changes

Comment: Not relevant to the question at hand but you need to get your upgrade path sorted out. 2008r2 has been completely unsupported for several years now.

Comment: it is not easy to upgrade this instance but we have plans for this. for now it must works like that. when i do encrypt = optional then it fails with  'invalid authorization specyfication' . the worst is that i would like to it to be encrypted using this expired certyficate ;P so best is encrypt = YES and trustserverertyficate - but this fails - why?

Comment: i was wrong even-  there is no cert on that server so guess some self signet it generated. is there any way that this new MSOLEDBSQL19 will accept and encrypt that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future searcherchers - i sow someone was posting here yesturday but deleted because of votedown

IT IS BUG IN MICROSOFT CLIENT
to resolve this we need to add `User ID=anything'`

so finaly like

`@provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;User ID=myUser'`

and this solves this issue.